Defining multiple states for a textInput component
My task is to create a TextInput component. My problem is, that I cannot define correctly the states from cva (my assumption is, they are not working for some reason?). How would I define one component, that can change based on criteria like: hasError, showIcon, isActive and so on.These are the Figma designs: enter image description here
And this is my code:
import HomeIconComponent from "./Icons/HomeIcon";
import {Field, Input, Label} from '@headlessui/react'
import ErrorIcon from "./Icons/ErrorIcon";
import { useState } from "react";
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority";

export interface textInputProps {
  disabled?: boolean | undefined; //if true, the input is disabled
  groupName?: string | undefined; 
  icon?: boolean; //represents the icon path
  label?: string | null; //represents the label name
  modelValue?: string | undefined; //represents the value of the input. To think, if it is necessary
  placeholder?: string | undefined; //displays value before user inputs something
  error?: string | null; //represents the error message
}

const textInputStyles = cva(['k1-h-[3.5rem] k1-w-[18.5rem] k1-p-4 k1-flex k1-flex-row k1-flex-no-wrap k1-justify-start k1-items-center k1-relative k1-border-solid k1-border-2 k1-rounded-l-3xl k1-rounded-tr-2xl'], {
  variants: {
    variant:{
      default: ["k1-color-red"],
      hover: ["k1-border-blue-70"],
      readonly: ["k1-border-yellow-70"],
      active: ["k1-border-sky-70"],
      error: ["k1-border-rose-80"],
    }
  }
});

const TextInput = ({
    disabled,
    groupName,
    icon,
    label,
    modelValue,
    placeholder,    
    error,
}: textInputProps ) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(modelValue || '');
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const showIcon = icon || false;
  const hasError = error || false;
  const isDisabled = disabled || false;
  //const isFilled = text !== '';

 const state = (() => {
    if (hasError) return 'error';
    if (isDisabled) return 'readonly';
    if (isActive) return 'active';
    if (!isHovered) return 'hover';
    return 'default';    
  })()

  return (
      <div className={textInputStyles({ variant: state })}>
      <Field className="input-field">
        {label && <Label className="input-label k1-pl-1 k1-pr-1 k1-flex k1-flex-row k1-justify-start k1-items-start k1-relative k1-top-[-1.25rem] k1-left-[0.75rem)] k1-uppercase k1-bg-white">{label}</Label>}
         <div className="input-container k1-flex">
         {showIcon && <HomeIconComponent />}
          <Input
            type="text"
            name={groupName}
            className="input"
            disabled={disabled}
            value={text}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setText(e.target.value);
              setIsActive(true);
            }}
            onFocus={() => setIsActive(true)}
            onBlur={() => setIsActive(false)}
            onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
          />
        </div>
          {error && (
            <div className="k1-pl-1 k1-pr-1 k1-flex k1-flex-row k1-justify-space-between k1-items-start k1-absolute k1-right-[0.75rem] k1-bottom-[-0.75rem] k1-bg-neutral-fg-hover k1-bg-white">
              <div>
                {error}
              </div>
              <ErrorIcon />            
            </div>
          )}
      </Field>
    </div>
  );
};

export {TextInput};


I have tried to define the states as shown in the code above. I am expecting that I can change the state and the design of the component will change. For example if an error is present it will transform the border, icon and text color into red.

Are you sure the variables have correct data? I just tried setting hasErrorto true and it worked.

What exactly is the question, or specific issue/problem, you have here? Please [edit] to clarify and provide better details. I invite you to take the full [tour] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Hi, so it looks like it works. The problem was with Storybook configuration.
